# SQL - Check if 2 date ranges overlap when NULL is a possibility

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm trying to check if 2 date ranges overlap. I know this has been asked before but none of the other questions seem to account for NULL dates.

For example,

StartA = `2020-11-01`, EndA = `NULL`

StartB = `2020-12-01`, EndB = `2020-12-31`

Here, they technically overlap since the A time span never ends, so using the formula `(StartA <= EndB) and (EndA >= StartB)` wont work.

Can someone explain the foluma I should be using here?

Comment: Is `null` always assumed to mean that it's ongoing out to infinity?  I.e., what's to say that `EndA != 2020-11-15` but just hasn't been entered yet? In which case they actually DO NOT overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take `NULL`s into account:

```
(StartA <= EndB or EndB is null) and (EndA >= StartB or EndA is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COALESCE()` function whenever needed for any of the columns for the possible cases. If only `EndA` can be **NULL**, then apply the function to that such as

```
StartA <= EndB AND COALESCE(EndA,StartB) >= StartB
```